# Cannot Reslove setName,setValue,setType method of class PropertyInfo in Android Project

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

```
PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
celsiusPI.setName("Celcius");
celsiusPI.setValue(celsius);
celsiusPI.setType(double.class);
request.addProperty(celsiusPI);
```

I use `ksoap2-android-full-2.1.2` in my project.

Comment: do post complete code and the `.jar` files you have used

Comment: Have you added ksoap2-android-full-2.1.2 as a dependency? Have you rebuilt after adding as a dependency?

Comment: yes I added it in dependency and rebuilt also

Comment: I want to post complete code but it give me more detail error. how to skip it

Answer (score 0):

if Celcius is a class, then use celsius.getClass() insted of double.class.

This is how I implement a ComplexClass in KSOAP-2 requset.

```
    //Complex-type class implementation
                    getPendingAmountInfo pendingAmountInfo = new getPendingAmountInfo();

                    pendingAmountInfo.altCustomerId = altCustId;
                    pendingAmountInfo.authToken = authToken;
                    pendingAmountInfo.imei = LoginActivity.imeiNo;

                    PropertyInfo pendingAmtproperty = new PropertyInfo();
                    pendingAmtproperty.setName("pendingAmountInfo");
                    pendingAmtproperty.setValue(pendingAmountInfo);
                    pendingAmtproperty.setType(pendingAmountInfo.getClass());

//Creating Soap request object
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                request.addProperty(pendingAmtproperty);
```

If your celcius is a complex class, you have to do like I have mentioned above.

Thank you :)